How to write a command with optional args to work inside tikzpicture under \draw?
I want to write a command with more than one optional argument that should compute a path to be \draw inside tikzpicture. Is it possible in any way?
(Intension is to extend the luaLaTeX package bezierplot to work with pdfLaTeX, so I cannot change current interface with many optional args).
MWE that demonstrates the problem.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}

% cmds with only mandatory: work under \draw
\def\cmdI#1{} 
\newcommand{\cmdII}[1]{}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\cmdIII}{m}{}

% cmds with optional args: don't work under \draw
\newcommand{\cmdIV}[2][]{}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\cmdV}{O{} m}{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw \cmdI{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw \cmdII{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw \cmdIII{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

No error up to here.

Then errors in every cmd after this point. 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw \cmdIV{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw \cmdIV[1]{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw \cmdV{1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Any clue on how to define commands with optional args useful in tikz \draw context?

Does it need to be a command? Can it be a key? This key can simply use \tikzset{insert path = {<computed path>} to insert a computed path.

The problem is: it takes \cmdV{1} 130 expansions and \cmdV[1]{1} 111 expansions to finally be expanded. TikZ will only try 100 times until it gives up. You could do \makeatletter \def\tikz@resetexpandcount{\tikz@expandcount=200\relax} \makeatother or something along those lines for the paths where you have to use this, but I believe a key solution is still a better approach.

this might be useful (maybe): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/725177/319072

To keep pkg interface, it should be a command with 6 optional args and 1 mandatory.

In luaLaTeX, the following works:
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz,bezierplot} \begin{document} \tikz \draw \bezierplot{x^2}; \end{document} and \bezierplot has 6 optional args!

@MiguelV.S.Frasson It uses \romannumeral to speed up the expansion: \newcommand\cmdV{\romannumeral`\^^@\xcmdV} \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\xcmdV{O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} m}{node {this makes a path with [#1][#2][#3][#4][#5][#6]\{#7\}}}.

The bezierplot package deploys a \romannumeral trick that triggers a full expansion surpassing the problem that TikZ gives up after it itself has expanded something a hundred times.
I'll show another way with \cmdX that works for any non-expandable types of arguments provided the last and only the last one is a normal m argument (in curly braces).
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\cmdV{\romannumeral`\^^@\xcmdV}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\xcmdV{O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} m}{%
  node {this makes a path with [#1][#2][#3][#4][#5][#6]\{#7\}}}

\def\cmdX#1#{\cmdXa{#1}}
\newcommand*\cmdXa[2]{\pgfextra{\cmdXb#1{#2}}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\cmdXb{O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} O{} m}{%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/insert path/.@cmd}% \tikzset{insert path={…}}
    node {this makes a path with [#1][#2][#3][#4][#5][#6]\{#7\}}
  \pgfeov
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw \cmdV[a][b][c][d][e][f]{g};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw \cmdX[a][b][c][d][e][f]{g};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thanks! Very useful.
